# Cannot Create an instance of MainView (UserControl) c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

im getting a an error when trying to create an instance of `MainView` which is a UserControl in my `GameLauncher.xaml` metro window.

Revelent code to the bug:

```
public MainViewModel(IDialogCoordinator instance)
{
    Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>();
    Scanner = new GameScanner();
    Scanner.Scan();

    Games = Scanner.GetExecutables(); // If i comment out this line. thebug goes away
    FilteredGames = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Games);
}
```

The method itself:

```
public ObservableCollection<Game> GetExecutables()
{
    ObservableCollection<Game> games = new ObservableCollection<Game>();

    foreach (Platform libDir in LibraryDirectories)
    {
        string[] gameDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(libDir.InstallationPath);
        foreach (var gameDir in gameDirs)
        {
            string[] exes = Directory.GetFiles(gameDir, "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            Game game = new Game
            {
                Name = new DirectoryInfo(gameDir).Name,
                Platform = libDir.PlatformType,
                Executables = new List<string>(exes)
            };

            games.Add(game);
        }
    }
    return games;
}
```

Where the view is being instanciated and throwing error:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="GameLauncher.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                      xmlns:views="clr-namespace:GameLauncher.Views"
                      xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                      Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
                      mc:Ignorable="d"
                      Title="Game Launcher"
                      Height="800" 
                      Width="1200" 
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                      Background="#151518">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Preferences">
                <MenuItem Header="Theme">
                    <MenuItem Header="Dark" Command="{Binding ChangeThemeCommand}" CommandParameter="Dark"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Light" Command="{Binding ChangeThemeCommand}" CommandParameter="Light"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Accent">
                    <MenuItem Header="Blue" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Blue"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Green" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Green"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Red" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Red"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Yellow" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Yellow"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Orange" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Orange"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Purple" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Purple"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Pink" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Pink"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Steel" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Steel"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Olive" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Olive"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Teal" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Teal"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Magenta" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Magenta"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Lime" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Lime"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Emerald" Command="{Binding ChangeAccentCommand}" CommandParameter="Emerald"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help">
                <MenuItem Header="About" Command="{Binding ShowAboutCommand}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <views:MainView></views:MainView> //instanciate the view, this throws the error

    </DockPanel>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

where the viewmodel is being instanciated:

```
namespace GameLauncher.Views
{
    public partial class MainView : UserControl
    {

        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel(DialogCoordinator.Instance);
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

error im getting when trying to instanciate the usercontrol in my metro window:
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path

Comment: Does your MainView.xaml.cs contain a parameterless constructor? Otherwise the designer cannot simply create a new instance as it doesn't know from where to get the required information.

Comment: yes the contructor is parameterless

Comment: Please add the C# code to your question as well :)

Comment: @Joelius ive added the c# code to the qs

Comment: Your picture shows that there is an unexpected null value in line 46 of your GameLauncher.xaml. If you expand the error does it give you more info?

Comment: @NeilB yes, after expanding the following error is shown: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path"

Comment: What is the line of code the error is referring to.

Comment: Line 47 of the picture. <views:MainView/>

Comment: It might be just a design time error. try just running it.

Comment: ok so i found out the root of the bug. its a method thats being called in the constructor of MainViewModel. but i have no clue why its causing it. i have posted the relevent code to the qs

Comment: What's the MainViewModel and where is the code for that? Have you searched all appearances of "path" to see which variable could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show the full code of MainViewModel?

Comment: You are setting games as a new observable collection, and then you call the 'GetExecutables()' which sets it as a different new observable collection.  Its likely not the cause of the problem, but is unnecessary.  Can you post the code where you instantiate the view and viewmodel?

Comment: @PaulGibson done

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated!